# Delphi. How to Disable/Enable controls without triggering controls events

Tags: delphi, dataset, controls

I have a DataSet (`TZQuery`), which has several boolean fields, that have TDBCheckBoxes assigned to them.

These CheckBoxes have "`OnClick`" events assigned to them and they are triggered whenever I change field values (which are assigned to checkboxes).

The problem is that I do not need these events triggerred, during many operations i do with the dataset.

I've tried calling `DataSet.DisableControls`, but then events are called right after i call `DataSet.EnableControls`.

So my question is - is there a way to disable triggering Data-aware controls events.

Edit (bigger picture):

If an exception happens while let's say saving data, i have to load the default values (or the values i've had before saving it). Now while loading that data, all these events (TDBCheckBoxes and other data-aware controls) are triggered, which do all sorts of operations which create lag and sometimes even unwanted changes of data, i'm looking for an universal solution of disabling them all for a short period of time.

Comment: If you were using action lists then you could simply disable the action list whilst updating the database

Comment: then don't use DB aware controls and do the linking yourself...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on Guillem's post:

**Turn off everything:**

Traverse each component on the form with the for-loop, shown below, changing the properties to the desired value.

If you want to later revert back to the original property values, then you must save the original value (as OldEvent is used below.)

**Edit**: The code below shows the key concept being discussed.  If components are being added or deleted at run-time, or if you'd like to use the absolutely least amount of memory, then use a dynamic array, and as Pieter suggests, store pointers to the components rather than indexing to them.

```
  const
    MAX_COMPONENTS_ON_PAGE = 100; // arbitrarily larger than what you'd expect. (Use a dynamic array if this worries you.
  var 
     OldEvent: Array[0.. MAX_COMPONENTS_ON_PAGE - 1] of TNotifyEvent; // save original values here
     i: Integer;
  begin                                 
   for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do 
   begin
     if (Components[i] is TCheckBox)  then 
        begin
          OldEvent[i] := TCheckBox(Components[i]).OnClick; // remember old state  
          TCheckBox(Components[i]).OnClick := nil;
        end
      else if (Components[i] is TEdit) then
         begin
           OldEvent[i] := TEdit(Components[i]).OnClick; // remember old state  
           TEdit(Components[i]).OnClick := nil;          
         end;
    end;
```

**Revert to former values**

```
 for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do 
 begin
   if (Components[i] is TCheckBox)  then
      TCheckBox(Components[i]).OnClick := OldEvent[i]
   else if (Components[i] is TEdit)  then
      TEdit(Components[i]).OnClick := OldEvent[i];
 end;
```

There may be a way to fold all of the if-statements into one generic test that answers "Does this component have an OnClickEvent" -- but I don't know what it is.

Hopefully someone will constructively criticize my answer (rather than just down voting it.) But, hopefully what I've shown above will be workable.

Comment: I've concidered using such code but i'm worried ComponentCount may change, or somehow mess up order of components in the form while actions are being taken

Comment: ComponentCount won't change and the order of the components won't change unless you're dynamically adding and removing components at runtime, AFAIK. 

@ertx: thanks for your necessary edit to the code.

Comment: @ertx: On second thought, I don't know why you added the Index variable. Using the for-loop variable "i" as a subscript, AFAIK, would work fine.

Comment: it would skip the indexes and record only those array elements, which represent TEdits and TCheckBoxes, resulting in an empty array elements (not sure if that would allocate more memory or not), either way it was an [0] hardcoded before, and i'll accept your answer, thank's for the effort

Comment: instead of taking the index, make a list of the pointers to the components you're disabling. Then when you are re-enabling them you can go through the list of pointers. This makes you indepent of whether between the dis- and enabling the componentcount changes. Just make sure to catch the exception, because a checkbox might have gone.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is following:

```
var
  Event : TNotifyEvent;    
begin
  Event := myCheckbox.OnClick;
  try
    myCheckbox.OnClick := nil;
    //your code here
  finally
    myCheckbox.OnClick := Event;
  end;
end;
```

HTH

Comment: This will not work since the code is templated and i do not know how many checkboxes might be assigned to a field, or which checkboxes are assigned to which field

Comment: Hmm ok, can you please ellaborate on how your application assigns the checkboxes to the fields? From your comment I understand these checkboxes are used in a grid. Am I guessing right?

Comment: No, I have an inherited form, in which, checkboxes are assigned manualy, in design-time, but checkbox is only an example i'm having same problem with TEdits etc.. I'll try to edit original post to give you a better view on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The internal design of the `TCustomCheckBox` is that it triggers the `Click` method every time the `Checked` property if changed. Be it by actually clicking it or setting it in code. And this is happening here when you call `EnableControls` because the control gets updated to display the value of the linked field in your dataset.

`TButtonControl` (which is what `TCustomCheckBox` inherits from) has the property [`ClicksDisabled`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TButtonControl.ClicksDisabled). Use this instead of (or in addition to) the DisableControls/EnableControls call. Unfortunately it is protected and not made public by `TCustomCheckBox` but you can use a small hack to access it:

```
type
  TButtonControlAccess = class(TButtonControl)
  public
    property ClicksDisabled;
  end;

...

TButtonControlAccess(MyCheckBox1).ClicksDisabled := True;
// do some dataset stuff
TButtonControlAccess(MyCheckBox1).ClicksDisabled := False;
```

Of course you can put this into a method that checks all components and sets this property if the control inherits from `TCustomCheckBox` or some other criteria.